# How to insert a subview with xib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, view

I'm confused something fierce over having multiple views.  I simply want to have a button on my main view that activates a new view, which in turn would have an (x) button which goes back to main view.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this with two separate .xib files.  How might this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved it by doing it this way:

```
 NewViewController *new = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
new.delegate = self;
new.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:new animated:YES];
[new release];
```

Comment: you could also do `[self.view addSubview:new.view]` and create your own animations.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest to just use the utility application as a template.

From there, you can see how you would load view controllers and nibs in order to bring up the new view followed by how you would exit it.

Comment: I have been studying it to no avail.  Oh well, time to go back to the books. ;)

Comment: On the utility application, take a special look at the - (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender function on MainViewController and then - (IBAction)done:(id)sender on FlipsideViewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You are using a navigation controller, right?

On the IBAction associated with a button tap on the main view, put

```
NewViewController *newView = ... // [alloc - init your view here if you haven't already]
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

And on the button on newView,

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: No it's actually not a navigation controller.

Comment: You should consider using a navigation controller, as this is how it is recommended to be done. Other than that, you can consider playing around with view.hidden, [view bringSubviewToFront:], [view sendSubviewToBack:], etc, to display what you need.

Comment: I actually did it it a slightly different way, see my answer.  But thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, you wanted a MODAL screen. You should have mentioned that in your question, makes things easier. :P